# PHP Static Method Thread

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, object

If I use method static how in that way :

```
<?php
class Login {
    public static function isLogged() {
         // Here all code, connection db, fetch , ect..
    }
}

if(Login::isLogged()) {
   echo 'ok';
}

?>
```

Could I run up against some errors with Thread execution?

I have read on Php.net that Apache(or other webserver) create a new thread for manage request, but for every thread running the memory is shared. Therefore I think that could to be a problem with synchronization. Right?

Comment: Defining the function static means you can call it without an instance of the class. It does not share it between different scripts executing concurrently

Comment: Therefore is it different from other languages as Java that the static method on different thread can interleave?

Comment: Are you using the PECL pthread?

Comment: No Mikpa, I don't use it.

Comment: Then you will not have any problems with synchronization

Comment: Does enviroment of execution hasn't the same memory?